# How can I write a submit form using bootstrap modal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a bootstrap modal in asp.net mvc 5. But I'm having a problem with modal which I can't submit data. I have had call a _regiserPartial View form my _Layout (Master Page).

my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(UserViewModel model)
    {
        var userViewModel = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel, User>(model);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            userViewModel.Status = true;
            _userService.InsertUser(userViewModel);
            model = new UserViewModel();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

my _registerPrtial View:

```
@model HoiCode.Web.Models.Users.UserViewModel
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div id="registerModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Resgister</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post))
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @type = "email", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.launchRegisterModal').click(function () {
        $('#registerModal').modal({
            keyboard: false
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

my _layout: I'll call _registerPartial from here

```
<a href="#" class="launchLoginModal">Register</a>
```

Comment: Why are you using nested forms?

Comment: @ekad from my _layout I have a navbar with a menu register and when I click to menu register it'll call a _registerPartial using bootstrap modal

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint in `Register` post method? If so, was the method called at all when you submitted the form? and please answer the question from my first comment, what's `<form class="form-horizontal">` at the top for?

Comment: Nested forms are invalid. Remove the outer `<form>` tag.

Comment: @StephenMuecke good answer thank you so much :) I have removed <form> tag and my code worked fine :)